# Dynamics AX 2012: In AxGridView edit mode, how to hide the save button

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012

I've an requirement where in i've to hide the save button in the edit mode of `AXGridView`.

How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the grid AllowEdit property - when you set it to false the save and cancel buttons do not render.

If you need it turned off for all rows set AllowEdit=false in the markup. 
If you need to hide the buttons depending on some runtime condition, subscribe to the grid OnSelectedIndexChanged event and set AllowEdit.

Markup:

```
    <dynamics:AxGridView ID="grid" runat="server" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="grid_SelectedIndexChanged"
    ...
    </dynamics:AxGridView>
```

Code behind:

```
    protected void grid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        grid.AllowEdit = grid.SelectedIndex % 2 == 0 ? false : true;
    }
```